# Getting a 'Assignment makes integer from pointer without cast' error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, cocoa-touch

And i can't seem to figure it out. Here's one of the lines it has trouble with:

```
hourToReadOut = currentHourInt - 12;
```

`hoursToReadOut` and `currentHoursInt` are both integers from the .h file. currentHourInt is always set to something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error is given when you assign a pointer to an integer:

```
int *intPtr;
int intVar;
intVar = intPtr - 12;
```

It looks like `currentHourInt` is a pointer, not an integer, are you really sure it's not?

Comment: in the .h file i had put 'int *hourToReadOut'. that's why. i couldn't figure it out, thanks for that. thought it might've been something obvious that i was missing.

Answer (score 1):

Did you maybe declare one as a pointer to an int? NSInteger* when you meant NSInteger or int* instead of int? Or is one perhaps an NSNumber object from which you should be calling intValue?